# Are there more common names for divergent and convergent blocks of code?

Tags: parallel-processing, block

I am doing research on parallel processing and reading up on basic blocks (instructions with 1 entry and 1 exit point). A block is said to diverge in an in/else statement, and converge at the end statement. Are there other terms that describe divergent and convergent or are they generally known as that?

Thanks

Comment: branching? not sure about the convergence part.

Comment: "control flow fork" and "control flow join" come to mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those would be *conditional* blocks.

Some architectures, such as NVIDIA's GPUs, provide a mechanism called *predication* to support divergence at the instruction level. When predication is used, conditionally executed instructions are said to be *predicated*.